# Android: nine-patch is centered on one device, but moves somewhat to the right on another

Tags: android, nine-patch

I have a nine-patch image I put on a the background of a full-screen view:

[image][image]

And it looks as I want it on 800x480 and 1280x720 screens: it is has some equal transparent space on left and right sides. But on the FullHD screen the clear space on the left side is twice bigger than the space on the right side. But I have only one black pixel on both sides, so the clear spaces should be equal.

Then I modified my image like this:

[image: original][image: scaled one]

And now it looks centered on FullHD screen, but moved to the right on 800x480. How can I make it look centered on all the devices?

Now first image looks like this on FullHD device (this is the bottom part of the view):

[image]

and the second:

[image]

and they look vice-versa on 800x480 device.

The layout is as simple as this:

```
    ImageView ib = new ImageView(this);
    ib.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    ib.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.scroll_both_ver);
    setContentView(ib);
```

Upd: The solution was to provide a copy in each of drawable-* folders.

Comment: Your 9-patches are difficult to differentiate at this size. You should provide magnified versions with a pixel grid.

Comment: Can you please give us a screenshot of both devices so we can actually se whats happening? thank you.

Comment: And please provide the full layout xml, as layouting nine-patch is tricky at times.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [9 patch image incorrectly streeched in xhdpi density](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22158213/9-patch-image-incorrectly-streeched-in-xhdpi-density)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 9 patch top center black area is not centered well, it has more space on the right than on the left. Not sure how this can explain your problem, but try to adjust it

Comment: I even deleted that area, it didn't help

Comment: 2 things to try:
If you use a background color instead of the image, does it fill the area
Put the same image in a drawable-xhdpi, drawable-dpi and drawable-mdpi, make sure it is not an issue of rescaling the image

Comment: My images were in drawable-xhdpi, and when I copied the second one to drawable-hdpi, it started to look ok on 800x480. Still, this doesn't explain why the first one looks right-aligned on FullHD, but it doesn't matter much now :)