# 9 patch image incorrectly streeched in xhdpi density

Tags: android, nine-patch

I have problems with a 9 patch image when displayed in XHDPI.

It seems as there were a bug in Android because when displayed in HDPI is displayed correctly:

[image: hdpi image]

but when displayed in XHDPI it makes a very strange effect (look at the middle of the tab that is semitransparent:
[image]

It's very strange and I can't see why it'sworking this way when in XHDPI. Basically de 9 patch is a one line gradient with some transparent margin needed for the viewpager indicator:

[image: nine patch image]

Comment: Why you left that much alpha pixels and you need only the blue color?

Comment: Becuase I'm using an external ViewPager indicator that I wan't to modify and with the alpha pixels I introduce some padding.
It's true that if I remove alpha pixels there's no problem, but I need them and I don't understand why it doesn't work, specially why it doesn't works only in XHDPI.

Comment: can you replace that image with gradient drawable? it's seems logic and will solve your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Yoah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/377014/yoah) put me in the right direction. My problem was that testing phone (Nexus 5) is not a XHDPI device, it's a XXHDPI device. And as scaling is needed to convert from XHDPI to XXHDPI what explains Yoah applies to my case also.

Answer (score 8):

I assume your image is saved under the hdpi folder and there is no image in the xhdpi folder. 
You can copy the image file to the xhdpi folder, or change the image to the following. 
When the screen is xhdpi, and the image is hdpi, before opening in it is scaled to be 50% larger, so sub-pixel stretching will do the effect you see.

[image: Image that prevents sub-pixel stretch errors]

Comment: Or put image in `drawable-nodpi`, but I don't like it.

Answer (score 0):

try this 9-patch image:

[image]

I hope this work.

**Edit**

try this 9-patch with padding from both sides:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I explicitly said that I want to maintain alpha pixels for padding or referenced explanation of why my original image doesn't work on XHDPI